# Cycling through non-minimized windows in Win8

Tags: windows-8, desktop

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles to all windows, including minimized ones.

Apparently <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> does something similar, again including minimized applications.

Can I somehow cycle through all open desktop windows, skipping minimized ones?

Comment: Without a hack or a third party software this is not possible.

Comment: @Devid thanks, please post it as an answer and I'll accept it (until eventually some good solution to do it appears)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately without a hack or a third party program you won't be able to do this in Windows.

Comment: alt+esc does something better but not exactly what I wanted (I mentioned it in the question).